# antlr3ide generates parsers and lexers without package info?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, antlr, antlrv3ide

antlr3ide seems to generate parser and lexer files without the package info where the java files are located (such as **package tour.trees;**, here the relative path  folder *tour/trees* contains the corresponding files `ExprParser.java` and `ExprLexer.java`).

The [official forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/antlrv3ide/forums/forum/768683) seems a bit inactive and the [documentation](http://antlrv3ide.sourceforge.net/) gives me not much help:(

Below is a sample grammar file `Expr.g`:

```
grammar Expr;

options {
  language = Java;
}


prog : stat+;

stat : expr NEWLINE
     | ID '=' expr NEWLINE
     | NEWLINE
     ;

expr: multiExpr (('+'|'-') multiExpr)*
    ;

multiExpr : atom('*' atom)*
    ;

atom : INT
     | ID
     | '(' expr ')'
     ;

ID : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+ ;
INT : '0'..'9'+;
NEWLINE : '\r'?'\n';
WS : (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+{skip();};
```

Comment: @BartKiers I didn't add additional **options** block for the grammar file?Should I have to?

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks for your advice:)I have now added a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package declaration is not something that antlrv3ide generates. This is done by ANTLR. To let ANTLR generate source files in the package `tour.trees`, add `@header` blocks containing the package declarations in your grammar file like this:

```
grammar Expr;

options {
  language = Java;
}

// placed _after_ the `options`-block!    
@parser::header { package tour.trees; }
@lexer::header { package tour.trees; }

prog : stat+;

...
```

Comment: It works!Thanks so much!However I'm wondering why antlr3ide do not add the package info where the generated source code lies?And should I need to add a null `options` block so that I can add `@parser::header` or `@lexer::header` if I use the default option for `Expr.g` file?

Comment: @HongxuChen I don't use `antlr3ide`, but I wouldn't know why it should override functionality that is already handled by ANTLR. And you can simply remove the `options`-block (`language=Java` is the default, so you don't need it), you don't need an empty one (if memory serves me, an empty `options` block is even illegal...). In case you add an `options` block, it should just be placed before the `@header` blocks. You're welcome, of course.